# Error in Laravel join

Tags: sql, join, laravel-5

I am trying to get results from 2 table using join, where i want result between time range from those 2 tables,

here is my code

```
$final_trade = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->join('exchanges', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('exchanges.id', '=', 'finaltrade.exchange_id')
                ->where('finaltrade.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->whereTime('finaltrade.created_at', '=', 'exchanges.start_time');
        })
        ->get();
```

when i add hardcoded time value instead of 'exchanges.start_time' it gives correct result but i want to add values from column,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell Laravel that it isn't a value, but a column name:

```
->whereTime('finaltrade.created_at', '=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'));
```

Comment: can i add 1 hour in DB::raw('exchanges.start_time') if yes, how i can do ?

Comment: Try `DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '01:00:00')")`.

Comment: looks like it works but let say current value is 9:30:00, after adding 1 hour it should be 10:30:00, i have value 10:20:00 it did not include it but include 9:49:00

Comment: we can subtract time also, right ? using SUBTIME() ?

Comment: for first hour and last hour, its done, but now i am doing it for remaining hours by skipping first and last hours but it gives empty result, i can see data in db

Comment: this is code i add for other hours, $other_hour_trade = DB::table('finaltrade')
            ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
            ->select('finaltrade.*')
            ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
            ->whereTime('finaltrade.created_at', '>', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '01:00:00')"))
            ->whereTime('finaltrade.created_at', '<', DB::raw("SUBTIME(exchanges.close_time, '01:00:00')"))
            ->get();

Answer (score 1):

The wrong code is `->whereTime('finaltrade.created_at', '=', 'exchanges.start_time');` change it to `->whereColumn('finaltrade.created_at', '=', 'exchanges.start_time');`

And corrected code is

```
DB::table('finaltrade')
    ->join('exchanges', function($join) {
        $join->on('exchanges.id', '=', 'finaltrade.exchange_id')
            ->where('finaltrade.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->whereColumn('finaltrade.created_at', '=', 'exchanges.start_time');
    })->get();
```

Comment: both can't be equal because created_at is datetime, and start_time is time field

Comment: I don't know ok!

Comment: thanks for your help this can be useful information in other case

Comment: can i add 1 hour in DB::raw('exchanges.start_time') if yes, how i can do ?